# Stream selenium display over the internet

Tags: selenium, video-streaming, puppeteer

I'm automating a selenium browser (python) to automatically get some info for users of a web app. However, instead of just running it headlessly on the cloud, I would like to somehow show the user exactly what's going on. Is there a way to mirror the activity of the browser on a web app (built with flutter)?

I'm willing to switch languages and, for example, use puppeteer instead if necessary

My only idea so far is to screenshot the screen multiple times and present them on the web app, but that won't really give me the seamless look I'm going for.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can record a video of your script. May be that helpful. Check the following link you can use it in any language I am sending for java language.
  https://www.tadigital.com/insights/perspectives/how-to-video-record-selenium-test-cases

Comment: If still not solved, see if screen recording via the [Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture) works to achieve your expected result.